Google Drive API returns empty result despite correct query
I'm using the Google Drive API to list folders at the root of my Google Drive. Despite my queries being correct, the API returns an empty result set. Here's my current setup:

I have a Google Drive folder named "Persos" containing subfolders for different personalities.
I use a service account for authentication.
I've shared the "Persos" folder (and all other files and folder to be sure) with the service account and given it "Editor" access.

Here is my code:
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.oauth2 import service_account

def authenticate_google_drive():
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'socials/service_account.json'
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    return service

drive_service = authenticate_google_drive()

def get_personality_folders():
    # Query for all folders at root
    query = "'root' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
    logging.debug(f"Query for folders at root: {query}")
    try:
        results = drive_service.files().list(
            q=query, 
            fields="*", 
            supportsAllDrives=True, 
            includeItemsFromAllDrives=True
        ).execute()
        logging.debug(f"Complete results from Google Drive API: {results}")
        
        files = results.get('files', [])
        logging.debug(f"Files at root: {files}")

        # Check for 'Persos' folder
        persos_folder = [f for f in files if f['name'] == 'Persos']
        logging.debug(f"'Persos' folder search result: {persos_folder}")

        if not persos_folder:
            logging.error("Dossier 'Persos' non trouvé dans Google Drive.")
            return {}

        persos_folder_id = persos_folder[0]['id']
        query = f"mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '{persos_folder_id}' in parents"
        logging.debug(f"Query for subfolders in 'Persos': {query}")
        results = drive_service.files().list(
            q=query, 
            fields="files(id, name)", 
            supportsAllDrives=True, 
            includeItemsFromAllDrives=True
        ).execute()
        logging.debug(f"Results from Google Drive API: {results}")

        folders = {folder['name']: folder['id'] for folder in results.get('files', [])}
        logging.debug(f"Subfolders in 'Persos': {folders}")

        return folders

And here are the logs:
Query for folders at root: 'root' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%27root%27+in+parents+and+mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27&fields=%2A&supportsAllDrives=true&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&alt=json
Results from Google Drive API: {'files': []}
'Persos' folder search result: []

I have ensured that:

The service account has Editor access to the "Persos" folder. (and all the others files and folders at the root of my Google Drive)

Google Drive screenshot

The service account is correctly authenticated.
Api requests received from the service account

Tried other query:
query = "'root' in parents" give the same result



i question weither or not you are even getting the persos_folder_id  like that

Found the issue. I removed "root in parent" in the query and it works
